# Hide application icon and lauch app on particular key press in android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I want to hide application icon and want to launch Activity on particular number combination. How to do this?

I had tried Launch application on particular number using Broadcast receiver as :

```
public class ApplicationLauncherReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    String compare_num="1369";
    if(number.equals(compare_num))
    {
        Intent myintent=new Intent(context,LauchActivity.class);
        myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myintent);
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}

}
```

Using this I am able to lauch application after dialing 1369 no. For hide application icon I had write following code in LauchActivity class onCreate()

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

using this application icon is invisible but when I tried to call 1369 no to lauch application it crashesh and through error as

> error: activity class does not exist.

How I can Hide application icon and lauch application on particular no combination. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was creating an activity-alias in the manifest

```
 <activity-alias
        android:name=".Launcher"
        android:targetActivity="com.packagename.activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

the `android:targetActivity` is the name of your launcher activity and remove the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` from any other activity in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

One of your activities will have the following intent-filter

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

If you remove that filter from the activity, then you will no longer see the launch icon.